# Name matlab figure file differently

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I want to print out matlab figure differently and let user to input file name each time. I am using print function which automatically save the name of the function that is define in string. so far I have this. I got this answer from here.

```
filename = gcf;
print(filename,'myfilename','-dpng','-r30');
```

which print out the figure with myfilename. I was wondering, is there anyway I can let users to input that string every times it prints out the figure? Always appreciate the help from stack overflow. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

- [`uiputfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiputfile.html) - Uses a *real* save dialog that would warn in the case of overwriting an existing file etc.

  ```
  [fname, pname] = uiputfile('filename.png', 'Please select a file location');

  % Make sure the user didn't hit cancel
  if isequal(fname, 0) || isequal(pname, 0)
      return;
  end

  % Create the filename
  filename = fullfile(pname, fname);

  print(gcf, filename, '-dpng', '-r30');
  ```
- [`input`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) - Prompt the user to enter a filename at the command window.

  ```
  filename = input('Please enter a filename:');
  print(gcf, filename, '-dpng', '-r30');
  ```
- [`inputdlg`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html) - opens a GUI prompt for the user to enter the desired filename.

  ```
  filename = inputdlg('Please enter a filename');
  print(gcf, filename, '-dpng', '-r30');
  ```

I would recommend the `uiputfile` approach, personally